# Protractor + chrome driver: Element is not clickable at point

Tags: angularjs, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I am having some trouble getting a basic protractor test to work.

**My setup:**

- I use requirejs so I init angular using angular.bootstrap(), not the ng-app attr. According to protractor docs this is not supported out of the box, but seems to work fine for tests that don' involve clicking.
- Protractor conf.json:

  ```
  "use strict";
  exports.config = {
      specs: '../E2ETests/**/*.js',
      chromeOnly: true,
      getPageTimeout: 30000,
      allScriptsTimeout: 30000
  }
  ```
- I use some third party jquery plugs which I wrap in directives, I suspect these might be part of the issue.

**The test:**

```
"use strict";
describe('When clicking should add stuff', function () {
    var ptor;
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get('https://localhost/myApp');
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    });
    it('add stuff', function () {
        // If I comment this, the test pass. 
        element(by.id('add-stuff-button')).click();
        // This does not matter fails on the line above..
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**The error:**

```
UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (720, 881). Other element would         receive the click: <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.124)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

**Thoughts**

The chromedriver do find the button, because if I change the id it complains that no element is found. So I think the problem is that the button moves from its initial position. As the element(***)  function should wait for angular to be done, I suspect that its the third party plugins that might interfere as they might not use angular api's fetching data etc. So angular think its done but then the third party plug populates and moves stuff around.

Any ideas what to do? 
If the third party plugs is the problem, can I somehow tell angular that third party stuff is going on and then later tell it when its done?

Thx 
Br
Twd

Comment: This happens if the chrome window is too small, try to add inside the beforeEach     browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);

Comment: Thx origin, works! Add as answer and i will tag it.

Comment: Also, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37815727/771848) for the things you can try.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should set window size in your config file

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
}
```

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, this is definitely the proper way to go about setting a default window size.

Comment: Changed answer to this as it seems as the more appropriate solution.

Comment: This is a great sanity check for all configs.

Comment: add these in protractor.conf.js instead: exports.config = { capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome', 'chromeOptions': {'args': ['--window-size=1690,1000'] } } }

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue as described in the OP, but this answer is not resolving the issue for me... In the command line where I'm running `protractor conf.js`, I get the error: ` Failed: unknown error: Element <a href="#/charts" target="_self">...</a> is not clickable at point (40, 229). Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope ult-loading modal-message ng-animate in-remove in-remove-active" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)"...`

Comment: Even though that is the element I want it to click on... Any other suggestions for how to resolve this?

Comment: what protractor version are you using?

Comment: I'm using protractor version 5.1.2

Comment: But I know that I am sending the click to the correct element, because I am calling `browser.wait()` to wait for the form on which the button is displayed to be displayed before calling `button.click()`....

Comment: Worked for me :)

Comment: @someone2088 I seem to have same problem like yours, Is there any other solution that worked for you ?

Comment: How about you write a exception handler that will reattempt to click 'n' number of times after a wait for elementToBeClickable check ?

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 25):

Following worked fine for me:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click();
```

Edit: If above does not work try chaining perform() method too(I got this as an edit suggestion, I have not tested it but somebody could verify it and comment)

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click().perform();
```

Comment: Hi @Aman  browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click(); didn't work for me, so i tried with browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click().perform();,  it just hover on the element. Not clicked. Can u please solve the issue.

Answer (score 12):

This happens if the chrome window is too small, try to add inside the beforeEach

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
```

Comment: Two problems with your code: There is no need to use browser.driver which would bypass protractor and go a layer underneath, to webdriver itself. You also shouldn't insert that code into a beforeEach() block - that's an overhead.

Answer (score 12):

Or simply use the Actions class:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(elem).click().perform();
```

Comment: Hi Raul, you are posting to an old question. Can you explain how your solution is better than the others that were already posted?

Comment: Ni Noel, I recently came across to this issue, so I start looking for solutions. I read this thread, tried the code, and figured out that the `actions` class needs also the `perform` method to be called in the end. The one who suggested this approach missed to include the calling of the `perform()` method. For some who doesn't have much experience with WebDriver, this makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, Raul, it solved my use case, where the material dialog closes and then I had test clicking on a button.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue but was not related to the window size but had to wait for ngAnimation to end.

So I had to wait until the element was clickable with.

```
    const msg = 'Waiting for animation timeout after 1s';
    const EC  = new protractor.ProtractorExpectedConditions();
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(model.elements.button.checkCompliance), 1000, `${msg} panel`);
    await model.elements.button.checkCompliance.click();
```

@note - I am using async/await node 8 feature, you could just as well convert this to regular Promises.
Also using `ProtractorExpectedConditions` instead of `ExpectedConditions` [see documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe It is not applicable in your case, but I've encountered the same problem and based on [Milena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4605727/milena)'s answer I've been looking for another element obscuring my button (in my case, a dropdown menu in the top right of my screen).

It appears to be the *Connected to Browser Sync* notification message sent by  **browsersync**, launched by **Gulp**. The message vanished after a short time, but after my onClick() call.

To remove the notification, in my gulpfile, I've added the notify: false param when initializing browsersync:

```
browserSync.init(files, {
    server: {
        baseDir: "dist",
        index: "index.html"
    },
    notify: false
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I fix this problem by using browser time sleep.

```
browser.driver.sleep(3000)
```

before giving click button

Comment: Sleep is not the best solution as Protractor provides you mechanisms to wait until elements are shown/clickable. Why waiting 3 seconds if the animation is done in 500ms? Wait just the necessary, not more.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the desired screen resolution through your protractor configuration file (e.g. `protractor.conf.js` or `config.js`) for consistent test behavior.

## For example with Chrome browser:

```js
exports.config = {
  specs: [
    // ...
  ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--window-size=1600,900',
        '--headless'
      ]
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

## Explanations

- `window-size` argument will launch Chrome with a 1600 by 900 window.
- `headless` will launch headless Chrome, allowing you to have your tests run with the specified window size (1600 by 900) even if your screen resolution is lower than that.

You may want to have two configurations, one for developers (without headless mode) who always have a high resolution screen and one for build servers (headless mode) where screen resolution is sometimes a mystery and could be lower than what your application / test is designed for. Protractor configuration file are javascript and can be extended to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and purely adjusting the screen size did not fix it for me.

Upon further inspection it looked as though another element was obscuring the button, hence the Selenium test failed because the button was not (and could not be) clicked. Perhaps that's why adjusting the screen size fixes it for some?

What fixed mine was removing the other element (and later adjusting the positioning of it).

Answer (score 2):

This works better than specifying the window size, in case you test need to run on multiple displays.

`browser.manage().window().maximize();`

Answer (score 1):

Other way, you can try this:

```
this.setScrollPage = function (element) {

    function execScroll() {
        return browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()',
            element.getWebElement())
    }

    browser.wait(execScroll, 5000);
    element.click();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try turning off any debug tools you might be using. I was using Laravel and debugbar and had to set APP_DEBUG to false.

Answer (score 0):

From [Gal Malgarit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1582030/gal-margalit)'s answer,

You should set window size in your config file

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 800);
}
```

If it still doesn't work you should scroll to the element's location

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(720, 881);');
element(by.id('add-stuff-button')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this was sometime caused by a top navigation bar or bottom navigation bar / cookie warning bar covering the element. With angular 2, when clicking it scrolls until the element is only just on page. That means that when scrolling down to click something, if there is a bottom navigation, then this will obstruct the click. Similarly, when scrolling up it can be covered by the top navigation.

For now, to get around the scrolling up, I am using the following:

```
browser.refresh();
browser.driver.sleep(3000);
```

I made sure that I removed the bottom bar by clicking to close it before the test started.

Answer (score 0):

That means the element is not within the visible area. There are several ways to handle this:

1. Force click the element regardless visibility

```
await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', $element.getWebElement());
```

2. Scroll to the element and then click

```
await browser.executeScript(`arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});`, $element.getWebElement());
await $element.click()
```

3. Maximize the working area of browser's window before tests

```
beforeAll(async () => await browser.driver
  .manage()
  .window()
  .setSize(1920, 1080)
);
```