# protractor-element not clickable at this point

Tags: javascript, export-to-csv, gulp-protractor

I am trying to test "export to csv" feature, I am getting an error 
 Element is not clickable at point (967, 125). Other element would receive the click:

Here is my code :

```
describe('csv download link', () => {
            it('should get the csv table export', () => {
                var exportToCsv = element(by.css('a[ng-click="vm.exportToCsv()"]')).click().then(() => {
                    var filename = 'lastPublishedPage.csv';
                    expect(downloader.downloadedFileExists(filename)).toBe(true);
                });
            });
```

Comment: When you watch, is the field on screen? This error can sometimes happen when the field exists, but needs to be scrolled to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question, please look at here

[Protractor + chrome driver: Element is not clickable at point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211751/protractor-chrome-driver-element-is-not-clickable-at-point/)

Here is the answer

You should set window size in your config file

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 800);
}
```

If it still doesn't work you should scroll to the element's location

```
describe('csv download link', () => {
    it('should get the csv table export', () => {
        // scroll to exportToCsv's location
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(967, 125);');

        var exportToCsv = element(by.css('a[ng-click="vm.exportToCsv()"]')).click().then(() => {
            var filename = 'lastPublishedPage.csv';
            expect(downloader.downloadedFileExists(filename)).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```