# browser.actions().mouseMove() creates syntax error with sendKeys

Tags: angular, browser, automation, protractor, action

I am working on an test automation and using protractor with jasmine framework. While handling an autocomplete **select** (selection drop-down i.e countries' name drop-down). I wanna send keys to this autocomplete select drop down in the way as `browser.actions().mouseMove(addMember.getLocationInput().sendKeys('UAE')).perform();` but it creates a syntax error. When i remove `sendKeys('UAE')` it removes syntax error but i have to send keys to it. Can any one help me to send keys to this **autocomplete select**. You can find the complete test case in the attached file. Thanks in advance

```js
it('Should add Instructor successfully',()=>{
        return new Promise((res)=>{
            let email = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)+1;
            addMember.getAddMemberSubMenu().click().then(()=>{
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    addMember.getFirstNameInput().sendKeys("John");
                    addMember.getLastNameInput().sendKeys("Doe");
                    addMember.getEmailInput().sendKeys(email+"@gmail.com")
                    addMember.getUserRolesInput().element(by.cssContainingText('option','Instructor')).click();
                    addMember.getCountryCodeInput().element(by.cssContainingText("option","UAE (+65)")).click();
                    addMember.getPhoneNumberInput().sendKeys('231321321321'); 
                    //Here is the syntax error
                    browser.actions().mouseMove(addMember.getLocation().sendKeys('UAE')).perform(); 
                    browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
                    browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.ENTER).perform();
                    addMember.getSaveButton().click();
                    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('people').then(()=>{
                            resolve();
                            res();
                            })
                        },browser.params.Waiting_time.AVERAGE);
                    });
                },browser.params.Waiting_time.HIGH);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: addMember.getLocationInput().sendKeys('UAE') returns promise not the element. But mousemove expects an element. So you have an syntax error

Comment: why dont you sendkeys to location element before mousemove?

Comment: It says that element not interactable

Comment: @VolkanAlbayrak I have seen that another tutorial that it is possible to send keys to mouseMove()

Comment: @VolkanAlbayrak it is like `browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.model("location")).sendKeys("london")).perform()`

Comment: Is your location field visible? I mean it is on the screen?

Comment: Yeah it is visible, before this test case I check its visibility in another test case

Comment: Could you please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211751/protractor-chrome-driver-element-is-not-clickable-at-point solution. It might be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response but it is not the solution. Anyways thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my above mentioned problem by Changing `browser.actions().mouseMove(addMember.getLocation()).perform()` to `browser.actions().mouseDown(addMember.getLocation()).perform()` which moves to the element, clicks there and then `sendKeys()` can be called

Answer (score 1):

I think that mouse move can't go in combination with sendKeys as you are doing. 
First you move the mouse over the element like this:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(addMember.getLocation()).perform();
```

And then if you want to send keys, you need another code:

```
addMember.getLocation().sendKeys('UAE');
```

Comment: I have tried it. It says that element not interactable