# Element is displayed , but not able to click on it

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, protractor

HTML CODE:

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiFab-root jss47 MuiFab-sizeSmall MuiFab-primary" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="add" title="Add"><span class="MuiFab-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
```

Here i need to click on the add button. Its displayed but not able to click on it.

Test Script:

```
it('Login', function() {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); //Since it is React JS application
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  browser.get('');
  var username = element(by.css('input[type="text"]'));
  var password = element(by.css('input[type="password"]'));
  var logInBtn = element(by.buttonText('Login'));
username.sendKeys('');
password.sendKeys('');
logInBtn.click();
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var add = element(by.css('button[title="Add"]'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(add), 5000);
expect(add.isDisplayed()).toBe(true); // Output = True
add.click(); //Output = Issue exists
});
```

Output:

> Failed: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (210, 100). Other
> element would receive the click: ...      (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
> (Driver info: chromedriver=88.0.4324.27 (6347fe8bf1e48bd0c54d07dc55ca011cf40861c9-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#450}),platform=Windows
> NT 10.0.19042 x86_64)

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/a/44724688/11270766

Comment: #1 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66128567/9150146

Comment: Problem didn't resolve after going through the above two links.